# Add to Favorites link (is it possible these days?)

Tags: hyperlink, favorites

I'm in a corporate environment. We have an internal web site with lots of pages that shows data for various employees based on a selected date from a drop-down list.  When they favorite a page, the selected date is in the URL so that gets favorite'd as well. I need to make it so when they add a page to their favorites, the date portion of the url is removed so they always come back to the latest date available. I know the AddFavorite functionality doesn't work anymore.  It's looking like I am going to have to make a link that redirects them to the current page without the date part of the url so they can favorite that. But that just seems clunky.

tl;dr I need to make a Favorite This Page link that removes the date part of the url. Is it possible without the use of the javascript AddFavorite function?

Comment: You should use POST requests rather than GET requests.

Comment: The site was written years ago before I joined the group that created it. I have to work with it as it is. No time given to rewrite all the pages.